# Is it possible to auto submit Form Input Value to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying something and I feel, i may have get answer from this forum.
Well, I am trying to post input values to a page, but unable to find the correct code for it.

Example:
I have a post page with following form tag:

```
<form action="/RequestingDownload.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="filename" value="PhantomBook.pdf" type="hidden"><br> 
    <input name="filesize" value="15MB" type="hidden"><br> 
    <input name="id" value="fs5ser" type="hidden"><p></p><div align="center">
    <input alt="Download" src="button-download.png" width="184" type="image" height="99">
</div>
</form>
```

So You can see the input values in above page, I am trying to redirect above form to "ReqestingDownload.php" page with SetTimeout then it will land to actual download page.
SO following form tag is putted in "RequestingDownload.php" page:

```
<form id="ponyo_form" action="/DownloadServer.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="filename" value="" type="hidden"><br> <input name="filesize" value="" type="hidden"><br> 
    <input name="id" value="" type="hidden"><p></p><div align="center">
    <input alt="Download" src="button-download.png" width="184" type="image" height="99">
</div>
</form>
```

Where as "ponyo_form" is for Timeout.
I know that there must be something php coding between value's blockqoute (" ") but i don't know what it should be.

I think I have explained it very well and clearly so that any expert can help me through.

Comment: Try to search by submit form or ajax in the site, you find what you're looking for.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly It doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: Neither does yor question. Show us the javascript that is posting your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you want to have a confirmation page before going to the download isn't it?

You have some page (called 1 as example) who sends a form to RequestingDownload.php (we call it 2), which goes to DownloadServer (we call it 3).

So, the page 2 should fill the the input fields of the form with the values sent on page 1.

You should use the $_POST['name_of_the_field_of_the_form'] like this:

```
<form id="ponyo_form" action="/DownloadServer.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="filename" value="<?=$_POST['filename'];?>" type="hidden"><br> <input name="filesize" value="<?=$_POST['filesize'];?>" type="hidden"><br> 
    <input name="id" value="<?=$_POST['id'];?>" type="hidden"><p></p><div align="center">
    <input alt="Download" src="button-download.png" width="184" type="image" height="99">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You Dear. That's what I was looking for. Glad that you picked my question and resolved the issue with exact solution what i needed. You are a true genius.